# Angular 2 - Http with promise return Undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-promise

i'am new on Angular2 and i'am trying to get data from a json file. To do this i'am using Http with Promise but when i do console.log from my promise variable they return Undefined.

> post.services.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http'; 
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Post} from '../interfaces/post.interface';
@Injectable()
export class PostService{
    private url = 'myjson.json';
    constructor(private http: Http){ }
    private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      console.log(body.data);
      return body.data || null;
    }
    getPosts(): Promise<Post[]>{
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }   
    private handleError(error: any) {
      console.error('An error occurred', error);
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

> posts.component.js

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';
import {PostService} from '../services/post.service';
import {Post} from '../interfaces/post.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'posts',
    template: 
    `
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <form (submit)="addPost()">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" />
        <br />
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="body" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
            {{1+1}}
            <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
    `,
})

export class PostsComponent implements OnInit{
    private posts:Post[];
    private title:string;
    private body:string;
    private newPost:Object;
    error: any;

    constructor(private _postService:PostService){}
    getPosts(){
        this._postService.getPosts().then(posts => this.posts = posts).catch(error => this.error = error);
    }
    ngOnInit() {        
        this.getPosts();
        console.log(this.posts);
    }
    addPost(){
        this.newPost={
            title:this.title,
            body:this.body
        }
    }
}
```

> post.interface.ts

```
    export interface Post{
    id: number;
    userId: number;
    title:string;
    body:string;
}
```

Please some one can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question with the specific code that you are having an issue with rather than make us hunt through your git repo.

Comment: I  have edited the post. Sorry about that.

Comment: Now you have far too much irrelevant code posted. Please review [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you about that. Edited again.

Answer (score 6):

It's because promises / HTTP requests are asynchronous. You need to add `console.log` within the callback of the promises for your HTTP request. If you do that outside this callback (i.e. right after executing the request), the response isn't there anymore so you'll have an undefined.

Here is a sample:

```
getPosts(){
    this._postService.getPosts().then(posts => {
      this.posts = posts;
      console.log(this.posts); // not null
    }).catch(error => this.error = error);
}

ngOnInit() {        
    this.getPosts();
    console.log(this.posts); // null
}
```

**Edit**

I think that the problem is in your `extractData` method. You shouldn't use `body.data` unless you have a `data` property in your JSON property.

```
    private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      console.log(body);
      return body || null; // <-------
    }
```

Comment: Now return NULL but not the posts. I dont know why.

Comment: I think that the problem is in your extractData method. You shouldn't use body.data unless you have a data property in your JSON property. I updated my answer accordingly